# How do you turn off comments on a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, administration, comments

I do not want users to be able to add comments to each row of my SharePoint lists.

How do I turn this feature off?

[image: Location of comment button on SharePoint List]

Comment: I have opened a new idea at SharePoint User Voice to [enable or disable comments on list items in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/42287590-comments-on-list-item-in-sharepoint-online), please upvote for this idea to get it applied soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://www.quixtec.com/blog/sharepoint/introducing-commenting-in-microsoft-lists/) it is currently only allowed at the tenant level for the entire organization.

> Admins can disable this feature at the organization level by changing
> the CommentsOnListItemsDisabled parameter in the Set-SPOTenant
> PowerShell cmdlet.

It also mentions that there should be new controls coming in 2021 that allow for site or list level.

> It is not currently possible to disable commenting at the site or list
> level. We hope to have those controls in a later update, likely in the
> first quarter 2021.

Sorry that I wasn't able to provide a better answer at this time. Of all the features that SP needs, I really don't see how list item-level comments was a thing we needed. SMH

---

Comment: Enable/Disable list comments at SharePoint **list level** will be available very soon. Check detailed information in [this article](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/05/23/enable-disable-the-comments-for-a-sharepoint-online-microsoft-list/)